# Lets encrypt renew in debian 9 ISPConfig Apache is ok but https fail because cert is EXPIRED

Tags: apache, debian, lets-encrypt, certbot

In a debian 9 server with ISPConfig updated , php 7.3 and lets encrypt. The renew of all certs is ok . But one of them fail when i try to enter the site with https. The browser says that cert is EXPIRED.

I make

`/opt/certbot/certbot-auto`

i get

`IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at:
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/fullchain.pem
   Your key file has been saved at:
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/privkey.pem
   Your cert will expire on 2020-03-10. To obtain a new or tweaked
   version of this certificate in the future, simply run certbot-auto
   again with the "certonly" option. To non-interactively renew *all*
   of your certificates, run "certbot-auto renew"`

then

`service apache2 restart`

ssllabs.com says that the cert is EXPIRED and browser doesn't accept the https connection.

Then i tried to revoke the cert to create  a new cert but then fails the apacche server and get this message:

```
Error while running apache2ctl configtest.
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

The Apache error log may have more information.

```
[Wed Dec 11 22:47:54.922290 2019] [alias:warn] [pid 25196] AH00671: The Alias directive in /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/squirrelmail.conf at line 49 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.                   
AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-ispconfig.conf:73                                                                                                     
AH00526: Syntax error on line 157 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/100-mallata.com.vhost:                            
SSLCertificateFile: file '/var/www/clients/client3/web3/ssl/example.com-le.crt' does not exist or is empty
```

Comment: Not a programing question. And the error message is clear: `'/var/www/clients/client3/web3/ssl/example.com-le.crt' does not exist or is empty`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From error log you can see your config point to the wrong certificates:

```
SSLCertificateFile: file '/var/www/clients/client3/web3/ssl/example.com-le.crt' does not exist or is empty
```

So you should edit `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/100-mallata.com.vhost` and edit it to point to the real full chain file `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/fullchain.pem` and private key `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/privkey.pem`

Something like:

```
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/fullchain.pem
```

Comment: @DanielGil, if you are happy with my answer feel free to upvote and/or accept it :)

Comment: I upvoted (but i have low reputation) and accepted it. Thanks a lot for your time wasted on this question.